# Changing the desktop to Xfce 4.10 temporarily/permanently

Tags: xfce

I installed xfce 4.10 in ubuntu 14.04. Could anyone please let me know how to restart with Xubuntu like desktop. I tried xfwm4 --replace. But with that all my taskbar disappeared with very few functionalities available to me. The only option left with me was restart the PC. I cannot see the option to change to Xfce during login.

I use 2 kernels

Comment: Have you already tried?: 
sudo apt-get install xfce4
and
sudo apt-get install xfce-desktop

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, then log in and enter `startxfce4`.